# Rails: Should I always define associations between models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following models:

```
class Aircon < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shop
  belongs_to :brand
  belongs_to :power
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :shop, :brand, :power
end

class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :aircons
  has_many :brands, :through => :aircons
  has_many :powers, :through => :aircons
end

class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :aircons
  has_many :shops,  :through => :aircons
  has_many :powers, :through => :aircons
end

class Power < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :aircons
  has_many :shops,  :through => :aircons
  has_many :brands, :through => :aircons
end
```

**Question 1**

As you can see, there is an appropriate association between each two models. Generally, I think it's not a bad idea to do this as long as it makes sense. What do you think ?

**Question 2**

Now, I want to add another model, `Model`, and set the following associations:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :brand
end  

class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :models
end
```

What would be an appropriate association between `Model` and `Aircon` ?

**Question 3**

Would you define associations between:

- `Model` and `Shop`
- `Model` and `Power`

If yes, what type of associations ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I recall Model might be reserved. You might have to use Make.

Q1
Linking Models both ways in Rails is a best practice.

Q2
Model :has_many => :aircons

Aircon :belongs_to => :model

Q3
I wouldn't have Power be a model. Really its an attribute of a Aircon. I'm guessing that Power is BTUs or Watts of cooling for an Aircon. Something all Aircons have.

You would then say Aircons.find_by_power(500..1000) to find all the Aircons that have power of 500 to 1000

Comment: **Q1** That's not what I meant. Of course, if you define an association of A related to B, you should define the association of B related to A. I meant if you have A, B, C, and D models, should you define associations between each two of them ? **Q2** Thanks, makes sense.

Comment: Only if that really is the most natural representation. Few things are naturally that complicated. I might consider refactoring my responsibilities. Sometimes we get carried away with dividing and actually make more work.

Comment: **Q3** I don't see what's wrong to have the power as a model, and how the power differs from shop/brand (except it is a number rather than a string). If that was not the case, how would you find, for example, all `Model`s that have power=6kw ?

Comment: Aircon.find_by_power(6000).map { |i| i.model }.uniq
arguably less efficient, but not difficult.

Comment: OK. How about the association between `Power` and `Model` ? I thought about `Power has_many :models, :through => :aircons`, but I'm not sure about the other direction (because each model belongs to a specific power).

Comment: I am not an airconditioning expert. However, I believe the airconditioning units themselves have the power, not the models. I would search Cars.find_by_horse_power(400) and then sort by makes and models. Power.find_by_watts(6000).airconditioners just doesnt feel right. To me it should be Airconditioners.find_by_power(6000). However its your project and you have the freedom to implement it as you see fit.